# How to make animation of image change for ImageView from Java code

Tags: android, android-animation

I wanted to make it with TransitionDrawable class, but it needs a separate file transition.xml. There I define which image I change to.

I need to define them in Java code because I don't know which images I will change too. I have many images and I accidentally get only two images which will change between each other. What can I do? Perhaps I need another class.

Code with transition.xml:

```
public class TransitionActivity extends Activity 
        implements OnClickListener {

    private ImageView image; 
    private TransitionDrawable mTransition;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setOnClickListener(this);

        Resources res = this.getResources();    
        mTransition = (TransitionDrawable)res.getDrawable(R.drawable.transition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        image.setImageDrawable(mTransition);    
        mTransition.startTransition(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programmatically create a [`TransitionDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html) using the class' [constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html#TransitionDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable[])). You don't need to acquire it from XML. This gives you the flexibility of dynamically assigning the Drawables it transitions between.

```
// drawable1 and drawable2 can be dynamically assigned in your Java code

Drawables[] drawables = new Drawables[] {
    drawable1, drawable2
};
mTransition = new TransitionDrawable(drawables);
```